# M Gemfile. What does this mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, railstutorial.org

I did:
`git checkout sign-up`

And got this:

```
M   Gemfile
Switched to branch 'sign-up'
```

What does `M Gemfile` mean? In the railstutorial.org (end of Ch 7 beginning of Ch 8) it doesn't display that line.

About 30 minutes ago I had to upgrade rake from 0.8.7 to 0.9.2 after I tried downgrading it, but I'm pretty sure it wasn't done cleanly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the file `Gemfile` is different from the one that's committed in your git repository. If you made changes (such as the version of `rake`), then that's what the difference is. To verify the differences and make sure you want to commit it to the repository, you can always do `git diff Gemfile`.

**EDIT**: To be clear, `M` stands for modified. [Here's a list of what each status means](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html#_short_format).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with M = modified status as above. In addition if you have a change in your Gemfile, you should run:

```
bundle install
```

to make sure that your environment matches your current gem set. This will also update your Gemfile.lock